# Find the U-statistics for a parameter

Tags: nonparametric, u-statistics

$X_1,\ldots,X_n, i.i.d.$

$p=P\left(X>0\right),\theta=p\left(1-p\right) $

How can I find the U-statistics of $\theta$?

Comment: what do you mean? A $U-$statistic is indeed a statistic. It can be used to estimate a parameter $\theta$. Is your question "how can I estimate $\theta$ via a $U-$statistic?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably want I want to ask, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't want to use maximum likelihood? Note that all you care about are $Y_i=\mathbb{1}(X_i>0)$ which can be modelled -without loss of generality- as $\mathtt{Bernoulli}(p)$ where $p:=\mathbb{P}(Y_i=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_i>0)$. The maximum likelihood estimator for $p$ is $\widehat{p}=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$, thus, by the invariance property of ML estimators the ML for $\theta=p(1-p)$ is $\widehat{\theta}=\widehat{p}(1-\widehat{p})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $U-$statistic that is unbiased for $\theta=p(1-p)$ would be
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{2}^{-1}\sum_{i<j}Y_i(1-Y_j),
\end{align*}
where $Y_i:=\mathbb{1}(X_i>0)$. Note that $\mathbb{E}[Y_i]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}(X_i>0)]=\mathbb{P}(X_i>0)=p.$ To see unbiasedness, by the fact that $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is an i.i.d. sample, we have that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\binom{n}{2}^{-1}\sum_{i<j}Y_i(1-Y_j)\right] &= \binom{n}{2}^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j<i}\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i(1-Y_j)\right]\\
&=\binom{n}{2}^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j<i}\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i\right]\mathbb{E}\left[(1-Y_j)\right] \\
&=\binom{n}{2}^{-1}\binom{n}{2}p(1-p)=\theta.
\end{align*}